# Knapsack recursivo en Python

Tags: python

Tengo una lista llamada `self.items`:

```
items = [dict(id=0, w=4, v=12),
             dict(id=1, w=6, v=10),
             dict(id=2, w=5, v=8),
             dict(id=3, w=7, v=11),
             dict(id=4, w=3, v=14),
             dict(id=5, w=1, v=7),
             dict(id=6, w=6, v=9)]
```

Con esto, tengo que hacer una lista de listas,donde cada elemento se combine con los otros incluyendo el caso vacío. La apariencia que tendrá al final esta lista de listas será algo así:

```
[[],[{id:0,w:4,v:12}],....,[{id:0,w:4,v:12}, {id:1,w:6,v:10}]....]
```

Después he implementado la función `brute_force()` para encontrar qué conjunto de elementos tiene el máximo peso permitido y el máximo valor.
Esta es la solución que he encontrado y me va bien:

```
 def brute_force(self):
    """ Solves the knapsack problem using brute force
    :return: max_value and list of items
    """
    power_set = self.power_set()
    best_value = 0
    best_set = []
    best_weight = 0

    for p in power_set:
        value=0
        weight=0
        for w in p:
            weight = w['w'] + weight
            value = w['v'] + value
            if weight == self.max_weight:
                best_weight=weight
                if best_value < value:
                    best_value=value
                    best_set=p


    return best_value, best_weight, best_set
```

Ahora debo hacer lo mismo pero de forma recursiva. Aquí es donde empiezo a tener problemas. Sé que el hecho de ser recursivo implica que no tengo que usar `for` porque ya lo hago al llamar a la función N veces, pero no sé cómo coger lo que quiero de `self.items`, que es el máximo valor. Con el `for` sí que sabría pero sin él no.

Ésta es la función recursiva de la que os hablo:

```
def recursive(self, n, max_weight):
    """ Recursive Knapsack
    :param n: Number of elements
    :param max_weight: Maximum weight allowed
    :return: max_value
    """
    self.iterations += 1 
    result = 0
    #
    # Add code
    #

    return result
```

Y esta es la solución a la que he podido llegar después de varias hora.

```
 def recursive(self, n, max_weight):
    """ Recursive Knapsack
    :param n: Number of elements
    :param max_weight: Maximum weight allowed
    :return: max_value
    """
    self.iterations += 1 
    result = 0
    #
    # Add code
    #
    if max_weight > self.max_weight: #they gave me the self.max_weightas a variable of method __init__ which shows me what is the maximum weight permitted
        self.recursive(self, self.items+self.iterations, max_weight)
        if max_weight < self.max_weight:
            self.recursive(self, self.items+self.iterations, max_weight)
        else:
                result = self.items['v']+result

    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Deberías cambiar de chip. Python tiene muchas facilidades para procesar listas y diccionarios sin necesidad de bucles `for`.

Para obtener todas las combinaciones posibles:

```
from itertools import combinations

power_set = sum((list(combinations(items,i))
                for i in range(0,len(items)+1)), [])
```

Para poder trabajar mejor, definimos funciones para calcular el peso y el valor de un conjunto:

```
def sum_weigth(p):
    return sum(x["w"] for x in p)

def sum_value(p):
    return sum(x["v"] for x in p)
```

Para seleccionar sólo los que no se pasen de un peso:

```
power_set_filtered = [p for p in power_set
                         if sum_weigth(p) < max_weigth ]
```

Una vez filtrados, nos quedamos con el de mayor valor:

```
best_set = max(power_set_filtered, key=sum_value)
```

Combinando todo, se puede simplificar más:

```
def sum_weigth(p):
    return sum(x["w"] for x in p)

def sum_value(p):
    return sum(x["v"] for x in p)

power_set_filtered = (p for i in range(0, len(items)+1)
                            for p in combinations(items, i) 
                                if sum_weigth(p) < max_weigth )

best_set = max(power_set_filtered, key=sum_value)
```